# Is there a tabbed console app for Windows that can remember its open tabs?

Tags: windows

I tried several different tabbed consoles, including [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), [ConsoleZ](https://github.com/cbucher/console), [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/), and none appears to able to remember/restore tabs (including the current path in each one). ConEmu kind of tries, but the paths in tabs are not preserved, so that is not useful.

Is there a tabbed console app for Windows that can restore tabs (with paths) when it is restarted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ConEmu](http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html) can. Just use the latest version. It will restore working directories, tabs, splits. However, read [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/ShellWorkDir#What_you_shall_do_to_get_CD_support) if you are using not only `cmd.exe`.

[image: Auto save/restore opened tabs]

Comment: Confirmed as working in alpha/140903, thanks!